# amazon sp api golang sdk Permission Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I'm trying to use SPI API programatically using Golang.
https://github.com/amazinsellers/amazon-sp-api-sdk-go and also tried with official https://github.com/amzapi/selling-partner-api-sdk and always have permission denied on the sample code on both github...

I followed this guide for all the IAM setup on my AWS Account but still not working..
https://spapi.cyou/en/guides/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.html#terminology

Here is my response json:

```
{"AssumeRoleResponse": {"-xmlns": "https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/", "AssumeRoleResult": {"AssumedRoleUser": {"AssumedRoleId": "AR***:SPAPISession", "Arn": "a
rn:aws:sts::123***:assumed-role/MyStsRoleName/SPAPISession"}, "Credentials": {"SessionToken": "FwoGZXIvYXdzEPb//////////wEaDJyejpfUNUYyux***=", "Expiration": "2022-03-14T13:41:14Z", "AccessKeyId": "A***", "SecretAccessKey": "Dr***"}}, "ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "b000db8e-e0f0-4150-b2fe-808d8212d599"}}}
{"code":"Unauthorized","details":"","message":"Access to requested resource is denied."}
```

My Dev App on Seller Central is on Draft status I passed the role I created on it like following :

```
arn:aws:iam::123***:role/MyStsRoleName
```

and on my code:

```
SPClientID     = "amzn1.application-oa2-client.123***"
    SPClientSecret = "26***"
    SPRefreshToken = "Atzr|**"
    SPAccessKeyID  = "AKI***"
    SPSecretKey    = "Xre***"
    SPRegion       = "eu"
    SPRoleArn      = "arn:aws:iam::123***:role/MySTSRoleName"
```

Is it possible to get some help, since 2 days blocked on that part and I found nothing that could help me fix that. I tried a lot of thing on IAM params nothing works.

Here is my inlined policy on my IAM User:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::123***:role/MySTSRoleName"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Policy arn:aws:iam::123***:policy/SellingPartnerAPI is like :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "execute-api:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

My role trusted entities:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123***:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the assume role policy on the target role?

Comment: Sorry @luk2302 did not understand the question :S

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html assume role policy = trust relationship = trust policy.

Comment: I edited with the policy

Comment: Please read and work through the link. Neither of the two policies can be used as a trust relationship policy in IAM. Without a proper trust relationship no assume role can ever work.

Comment: I edited, I did a check on this guide step by step. I don't know where is the mistake... It's the same.

Comment: @X6Entrepreneur I have the same frustrating issue with any Go SP API. Everything seems correct, checked docs carefully 100 times. Always get "Access to requested resource is denied." Did you manage to fix it?